# My wireguard install has broken and I'm unable to fix it

Tags: networking, macos

Since I've installed Wireguard on my MacBook Air running MacOS Sierra it hasn't given me any major problems until now. I've been using [wgcf](https://github.com/ViRb3/wgcf) to generate the wireguard config file, but I don't think that has been the cause of my issues with wireguard. So, in the last day or two when I run `wg-quick up ~/wgcf/wireguard-profile.conf` it prints three lines and then hangs.

```
[#] wireguard-go utun
[+] Interface for wgcf-profile is utun1
[#] wg setconf utun1 /dev/fd/63
```

These are the current versions I have installed:

```
wireguard-go v0.0.20210212-10-g2fa6aab
wireguard-tools v1.0.20200827 - https://git.zx2c4.com/wireguard-tools/
go version go1.16 darwin/amd64
```

I've been trying to fix this in all different kinds of ways from using brew to uninstall and reinstall wireguard-tools and wireguard-go. I manually downloaded the latest version of go and wireguard-go and it still hangs like it did before. At this point I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error in a similar situation.

My `wireguard-go` had somehow updated to `0.0.20220117`, while my `wireguard-tools` was trailing at `1.0.20200513`.

I ran:

```
brew upgrade wireguard-tools
```

Which updated it to `1.0.20210914`, and then `wg-quick up ~/.config/wireguard/wg0.conf` started working again for me.

NOTE: A sysadmin at the company also restarted the Wireguard server at the same time, so that could have also contributed to it working.